# Customize MSIX package layout

Tags: windows, uwp, packaging, msix

The default layout of the MSIX package installer is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8v2Q.png). Is it possible to customize the UI adding the description of the app, terms and conditions section, checkbox buttons like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeIxv.png)?

Answer (score 2):

No. MSIX apps are designed to install without user intervention and without any customization. Currently if you need any disclaimers or customization you have to do that on first run of your app.

If you want to suggest changes to the current design then you can open an issue on the [MSIX GitHub page](https://github.com/microsoft/msix-packaging/issues)